# No kit found: qt error

Tags: windows, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am using qt 4.8.6 Mingw edition and using qt creator 3.x as an IDE.
When I tries to open a new project it says no kit found. And when I try to add a kit with qmake It gives me an error saying mkspec not found for qt version.
Please help, I am a newbie to qt.

Edit: I am using windows and installed qt from its setup from qt-project.io

Comment: Which OS? How did you install Qt libs and Qt Creator?

Comment: Do you have Qt command prompt (in the Programs, under some Qt section), created by SDK installation? Does qmake work from there?

Comment: Why do you use version 4.8? Do you really need that version? Have you try the latest version?